# Functional type annotation in swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming, swift3

To call a function with arguments, It need to write each parameter together in Swift 3.0. 
But once assign function to constant with type annotation, then there is no need to write each parameter. Why?

```
func foo(base : Int) {
    print ("param = \(base)") 
}

// Case 1 
let s : (Int) -> () = foo

s(5) // SUCCESS!
s(base:5) // Error!

// Case 2
let k : (base: Int) -> () = foo

k(5) // Error!
k(base: 5) // SUCCESS!

// Case 3 
let t = foo 

t(5) // Error!
t(base: 5) // SUCCESS!
```

Comment: You *can* given the closure parameters names with `let s: (base: Int) -> () = foo` or simply `let s = foo`.

Comment: Although note that providing parameter names for function types will be disallowed in a future version of Swift 3 – see [this evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md).

Answer (score 1):

Because you can assign a more specific object to a variable of a more general type (e.g. a subclass object to a superclass variable, but we're not talking about classes here), but not vice versa.

`(base: Int) -> ()` is a more specific case of a general `(Int) -> ()` function. So, any `(base: Int) -> ()` is a `(Int) -> ()` function, but not any `(Int) -> ()` function is a `(base: Int) -> ()` function.

And later, when you use the variable that you created, Swift treats it according to its type. If it is `(base: Int) -> ()`, then the argument name is required, else it's not required.

So, in the first case you explicitly declare the variable as `(Int) -> ()` and use it accordingly. Swift doesn't make any assumptions on these lines:

```
s(5) // SUCCESS!
s(base:5) // Error!
```

It only knows that the variable has a type `(Int) -> ()`. It can be any other `(Int) -> ()` function like `(whatever: Int) -> ()`, for instance.

In the second case the variable is explicitly created as `(base: Int) -> ()`, so to use it the name should be specified.

In the third case the variable is *implicitly* created as `(base: Int) -> ()` (Swift infers the type automatically).

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    let location : NSString = Txtsrch.text! as NSString
    let geocoder : CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location as String, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if((error) != nil){
            print("Error", error)

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Search Invelid", message: "Please Enter Valid Place", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        else
        {


            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                let coordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
            }
            if (placemarks!.count > 0) {
                print(placemarks![0])
                let topResult : CLPlacemark = placemarks![0]
                let placemark: MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(placemark: topResult);
                self.lat = (placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
                self.lng = (placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
                print("coordinate=",placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude)
                var region: MKCoordinateRegion = self.mapli!.region;
                region.center = (placemark.location?.coordinate)!;

                region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                self.mapli!.setRegion(region, animated: true);
                self.mapli!.addAnnotation(placemark);
                self.bool = true

            }
        }

    })


}
```

Answer (score -2):

when you do the "shorthand", you're creating an "s" that's a generic type, of any function that meets the signature requirement of having an input parameter of type Int and no return value.

When you assign foo to that constant you meet the type requirement, and foo is now "nested" inside s.

Maybe...